# Why is Rider wearing Pants?

Tags: fate-zero

When Risei Kotomine issues the temporary suspension of the Holy Grail War in order to hunt down and destroy Caster, Waver makes a deal with Rider, that if he destroys Caster, he will buy him a pair of pants so he can freely explore outside.

Yet in Episode 9 before the two even find Caster's hideout at the time Rider is wearing pants. What happened to the deal? Neither of them was present during the attack on the Einzbern castle and it was in broad daylight so Rider can't have stolen them when he went to collect the water samples for Waver.

Comment: Maybe the pants were given in faith of the job eventually getting done. It would be kinda hard to search if you can't explore properly as the pants would have allowed Rider to do.

Answer (score 4):

Waver does say in Episode 7 that he'll buy Rider some pants as a reward for taking out Caster. In the novel he tells Rider in Volume 2, Act 5, -140:41:54, that he'll buy him a pair of pants if he can defeat even one of the other Servants.

> [Waver] “Your majestic achievements and your trousers are two completely
>   irrelevant things! Before you go out to enjoy yourself, show me what
>   you can! Kill at least one of the opponents’ Servants!”
>
> [Rider] “Eh? You are quite an impatient fellow. You can engage a Servant in a
>   combat anytime you want, you know.”
>
> [Waver] “So do it now! Kill at least one of them! If you do that, I’ll buy you
>   trousers or anything you want.”

Later, in Episode 9 of the anime, we find out that Waver caved and bought the pants for Rider so he would be able to go outside and get the water samples that would let Waver isolate the location of Caster's workshop. In the novels, this occurs in Volume 2, Act 8, -108:27:55.

> [Rider] “No no. He is the one who has been of help to me. These trousers, even
>   he had chosen and bought it for me. Looks great on me, doesn't it!”
>
> At the time when he was entrusted with external businesses, Waver got
>   stuck with buying stuff for him, and bought an XL-size washed-jeans
>   for Rider, which he proudly showed off.

So Waver ended up having to buy the pants for Rider early so that Rider could go out and gather water samples without looking strange or attracting attention.